# How to install .netframe work 4.5 in windows7

Tags: .net

My probelm is I try to install github desktop but it fails because it asks .netframe work 4.5 but in my widows7 operating system have .netframe work3.5.
I try to install .netframe work4.5 it shows an error saying installation did not succeed.

Comment: How did you try to install the .net framework?   Did you download it from Microsoft?  What exact errors do you get?  Also, is this Windows 7 Home or Professional?

Answer (score 0):

I think you must install Dot net framework 4.0 first and then install 4.5. Make sure you are installing correct compatibility version 32-bit or 64 bit.

Use below link to download framework.
https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=30653